# Subset and filter a dataframe by logical operators and select the foregoing rows

Tags: r, subset, logical-operators

I have the following "random" Dataframe and want to apply a subset based on logical operators and then want to extract the foregoing rows:

```
set.seed(3)
Sample_Data <- data.frame(A = c(1:100, 1:100, 1:100), B = c(100:1, 100:1, 100:1))
print(Sample_Data)
Test_subset <- subset(Sample_Data, subset = A == 1 & B == 100)
Test_subset
    A   B
1   1 100
101 1 100
201 1 100
```

To make the subset with logical operators is no problem.
But now I want to know whether it is possible to create the following filter in R: "Filter all lines with the following criteria (see above) and also output the 10 lines in front of the correspondingly filtered lines."
Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: How can you select "the 10 lines in front of" line #1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in a comment, it does not make sense to filter rows that do not exist (there are none before row #1). Therefore, here's a solution for a filtering with slightly different parameters. Say, you want to filter target rows where `A == 11 & B == 90` (this value combination also occurs 3 times in your data) and you want to get the five rows preceding the target rows. You can first define a function to get the indices of the rows in question:

```
Sequ <- function(col1, col2) {
  # get row indices of target row with function `which`
  inds <- which(col1 == 11 & col2 == 90) 
  # sort row indices of the rows before target row AND target row itself
  sort(unique(c(inds-5, inds-4, inds-3,inds-2, inds-1, inds)))
}
```

Next you can use this function as input for `slice`:

```
library(dplyr)
Sample_Data %>%
  slice(Sequ(col1 = A, col2 = B))
    A  B
1   6 95
2   7 94
3   8 93
4   9 92
5  10 91
6  11 90
7   6 95
8   7 94
9   8 93
10  9 92
11 10 91
12 11 90
13  6 95
14  7 94
15  8 93
16  9 92
17 10 91
18 11 90
```

Comment: That function solved my problem, thank you!

P.S.: yes, my approach made no sense for the data set selected here with the filter options that I have chosen, I haven't considered that

Comment: f it solved your problem, why not accept the answer or at least upvote it?

Comment: because my reputation is too low :(

"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." This is what i get, when i upvote your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column with row number to make this process easier.

```
Sample_Data$row <- seq(nrow(Sample_Data))
Test_subset <- subset(Sample_Data, subset = A == 1 & B == 100)
Test_subset

#    A   B row
#1   1 100   1
#101 1 100 101
#201 1 100 201
```

For every row in above subset select the next 10 rows.

```
result <- Sample_Data[unique(c(t(outer(Test_subset$row, 0:10, `+`)))), ]
result

#     A   B row
#1    1 100   1
#2    2  99   2
#3    3  98   3
#4    4  97   4
#5    5  96   5
#6    6  95   6
#7    7  94   7
#8    8  93   8
#9    9  92   9
#10  10  91  10
#11  11  90  11
#101  1 100 101
#102  2  99 102
#...
#...
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer is also a good solution for my problem!